# Struts2-jQuery dialog bug in IE9?

Tags: jquery, struts2, dialog, internet-explorer-9

I'm using the [Struts2-jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) and am having some issues with dialog boxes in IE9.  The issue can be seen at the plugin Showcase at http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action.

Try this in IE9 to see the problem:

Navigate to the *Dialog* examples --> *Dialog Open on Click* example and click on the *Open modal dialog* button, you'll see the screen grey out but the dialog box does NOT appear.

Any advice?

Comment: Ajax tag libraries are brittle and always slightly out of date with the JS libraries they follow.  There may be a bug I don't know but using jQuery outright will in general make your life easier. Advice: Avoid the ajax tag libs (the standard S2 tags however I find very valuable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try out the current SNAPSHOT from Maven Repository? This includes the latest jQuery UI. I think this is the source of your this problem.

http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/

Comment: I've tried both [struts2-jquery-plugin-3.0.0-20110426.165506-6.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/struts2-jquery-plugin/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.0.0-20110426.165506-6.jar) and [struts2-jquery-plugin-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/struts2-jquery-plugin/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) in my application and neither of them solve the problem.  I will try it again tomorrow with simpler code to rule out any other issues.

Comment: I just tested it again using the code that you have in your Showcase example for _Dialog open on Click_ and it still does not work in IE9. With the new jar file, the `<sj:a...>Open modal dialog</sj:a>` code does not render a button in IE9 and is NOT clickable. This same code with the updated jar still works in Chrome..

Comment: Looks like a jQuery IE9 Bug. The SNAPSHOT is using the latest resources.

Comment: Don't know if this applies, but the example on the jQueryUI page seems to work fine in IE9.  See http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: I've been keeping track of new development releases you have and the latest one at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/struts2-jquery-plugin/3.1.0-SNAPSHOT/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.1.0-20110617.145944-9.jar seems to have fixed the issue I was having!  Have **not** done thorough testing of it yet though.  Will test it a little more thoroughly when I get a chance.

Comment: Great News! Thanks for testing.